# Converting single-phase to three-phase for City & Guilds 2391 practical

Tags: three-phase, single-phase

For my [City and Guilds 2391 course](https://www.cityandguilds.com/qualifications-and-apprenticeships/building-services-industry/electrical-installation/2391-electrical-inspection-and-testing#tab=information), I will be testing a three-phase distribution board with a motor and single-phase sub-main.

I am finding it hard to memorize the test procedures. So for me it's about repetition, but naturally I don't have a three-phase supply at home.

I want to buy a [Clarke PC 60 three-phase converter](https://www.clarkeinternational.com/shop/product/details/pc-60-5-5hp-phase-converter/path/phase-converters-2) ([instruction manual](https://dccf75d8gej24.cloudfront.net/documents/PC20-40-60%20Phase%20converters.pdf)).  Now AFAIK for the single-phase sub-main to work, I would require a neutral because single-phase loads aren't balanced or something like that. It's been a while since I studied three-phase theory.

The converter only has a 4 pin TP and earth plug, so no neutral. I just wanted to check with people more knowledgeable, can I just run a neutral separately from the wall socket feeding the converter? I don't see why not, because it's the same supply.

I might even be able to do it internally for a cleaner install, but I have to return the converter afterwards so I can't be taking it apart.

Comment: We are talking about a 400Y/230V, IEC-style three phase supply, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

L1 of the 230V source is connected to L1 of the 400V output. Therefore you will get 230V between L1 of the 400V output and the source neutral. Loads connected between L2 and L3 of the output and neutral will be supplied with 400V. I suspect that will prevent a proper test of the distribution board, but I know nothing of the board or the test.

Comment: yeah it's not strictly ze of the distribution because it the zs of ring main powering the converter.